# How to Change Column Width for All Word Tables at Once

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a lot of (> 200) tables in Word that have the same layout (two columns, six rows).

I need to adjust the column widths for all of them. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a VBA macro to resize every table.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> in Word and insert the macro under *Project » ThisDocument*.
Execute the code with <kbd>F5</kbd>

```
Sub resizeTables()    
  For Each Table In ActiveDocument.Tables
    On Error Resume Next
    Table.Columns(1).Width = 200
    Table.Columns(2).Width = 300
    On Error GoTo 0
  Next    
End Sub
```

- `Columns(2)` represents the column 2 in every table
- The value `Width = 300` is your desired width in pixel. Change it to your needs
- If your table has less columns than your VBA macro, you will get an exception.  For this, I added `On Error Resume Next` to ignore errors and `On Error GoTo 0` to stop this error handling